# SASS with bourbon mixin for backgrounds

Tags: css, sass, bourbon

I have included [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io/) and am trying to create a background using `@include background` as shown below:

```
@include background(url("images/head-icon.png") no-repeat 10px 10px);
```

But when compiled this creates two CSS background statments as shown below:

```
  background: url("images/head-icon.png") no-repeat 10px 10px;
  background: url("images/head-icon.png") no-repeat 10px 10px;
```

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following custom mixin

```
// folder,filename,extension,repeat,x-pos,y-pos
@mixin background ($img:file, $type:png, $repeat:no-repeat, $x:0, $y:0) {
    background-image: url(/images/#{$img}.#{$type});
    background-repeat: #{$repeat};
    background-position: #{$x}px #{$y}px;
}
```

Then

```
@include background(head-icon,png, no-repeat, 10, 10);
```